# Difference between params and query in vue router?

Tags: components, vue.js, vue-router

I cannot clearly figure out the difference between params and query in vue router. I met a case recently that makes me confused. There are page A and page B, I want to route from page A to page B, page B uses dynamic route (for example '/user/:id/:age/:address') and the data come from params object (get id, age, address from params), when I reload page B, it failed and throw a 404 not found (cannont get /user/1/24/xxxstreet). I can reload the page if I use query rather than params (for example '/user?id=1&age=24&address=xxxstreet'). So may anybody help me figure out the difference between params and query in vue router?

Comment: Show us your code please (Router, components...)

Comment: As per the documentation

https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to

<!-- named route  using params-->
<router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</router-link>

<!-- with query, resulting in `/register?plan=private` -->
<router-link :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }}"
  >Register</router-link

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For best rest api design practices, they are used in different contexts.

Params are the resources you are trying to fetch. 
Example: `user/:id` means you are accessing a user resource.

Queries are used when you want to filter those resources. 
Example: `users/?age="20"` means you are filtering a set of users whose age is equal to 20.

Comment: are params the dynamic part in the URL, like :id (before the ?) and query is just the part after the ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.